# Sharing Yubikey between host and VMWare

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation, yubikey

I have a Yubikey 4 working on my Win10 host machine, but *also* want to use in my VMWare Workstation 12 Win7 session.

At first, connecting to the shared Yubico device failed, because Windows could not find a driver:

[image]
[image]

This is a known issue, and [Yubico suggests to edit the .VMX file](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000008891-troubleshooting-vmware-workstation-device-passthrough) and add the lines:

```
usb.generic.allowHID = "TRUE"
usb.generic.allowLastHID = "TRUE"
```

After that, a '*non-shared*' Yubico key shows up, but this says **(Disconnect from host)**. That I do not want, I want to be able to use the Yubico on host and VM 'simultaneously':

[image]

At first I thought I could still try this because: When my VM starts up I'm already logged in to the host, so who cares about the VM *then* taking over the device? So I went on and connected to the device:

[image]
[image]

But alas, that does not work. When starting the VMWare session:

[image]

... and the Yubikey is disconnected from the VM (situation as in 3rd picture).

**How can I make my YubiKey 4 work with both the host and the VM session?**

Comment: Usually you can't share devices between host and guest. You'd need an additional abstraction layer to limit interaction with the device from both endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The important part is, that the YubiKey is statefull and that the state in the key and the state in the host must be in sync. If you were to have two hosts (no matter if one of them is a VM) connect to the key at the same time, then a state change in one would not be reflected in the other and vice versa.

This is not a limitation of VMware Workstation or Windows - it is a property of the way the YubiKey (and the overwhelming majority of USB devices) is built: Even something as simple as a USB-to-RS232 Adapter can't overcome this, it is rooted in the pricipal design of USB, that relies on a hierarchy of a host (the master) and a device (the slave) - no slave can server two masters.